# Using FeignClient to get data from external service

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to get data from external service and put the in database.

```
@FeignClient(value = "name-feign", url = "http://localhost:8081")
public interface Client{

    @PostMapping("/Efforts")
    List<EffortsResponse> getAllEfforts();

}
```

I added @EnableFeignClients annotation on my app. I know what feign client do.

what is the best way to do it?

Comment: what do you mean by `build the structure`?

Comment: infrastructure :) typo.

Comment: So what do you want exactly and what is your problem?

Comment: I actually dont know how to put it in database in this case..

Comment: Do you already have declared anything about your database? Like a repository?

Comment: Yes i create a jpa repository. ım not really sure what is gonna be my service layers actually. In my opinion , i can call the feign client service again on my service layer and get the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject the `feign client` and `repository` into the `service`.

There should have a method in the `service` like this:

```
@Service
public class Service {
  private final Client client;
  private final Repository repository;

  public Service(Client c, Repository r) {
    this.client = c;
    this.repository = r;
  }

  public yourMethod() {
    List<EffortsResponse> items = client.getAllEfforts();
    //some transformation: items => entities
    respository.saveAll(entities);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add @Autowired.

Comment: @Milgo it is not necessary actually.